# train_test_split weird x_test prediction results

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Does anyone know why you get different results when you split the dataset by yourself and when you split it with train_test_split?

splitting with the train_test_split:
[train_test_split function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSl3z.png) (Red is y_test, green is prediction)
In this cases my loss and val_loss are pretty good.

splitting by myself:
[Own splitting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jq50D.png) (Red is y_test, green is prediction)
In this cases the loss and val_loss are not so great.

I'm new in this and I'm playing predicting stock prices so I don't know what I'm missing here.

Thanks in advance for your help.

```py
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as web
import plotly.express as px
#import plotly.graph_objects as go
from copy import copy
#from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
#import plotly.figure_factory as ff
#from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error, mean_squared_error
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
import math as math
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date
today = datetime.now().date()

symbol = 'MSFT'
stock_data_source = 'yahoo'
start_date = '2010-01-01'
end_date = today
window = 30
percentage_test_dataset = 20 / 100

def interactive_plot(df_true,df_test,df_xtra,df_fut):
  fig = px.line(title = f'Price {symbol} Prediction')
  for i in df_true.columns[1:]:
    fig.add_scatter(x = df_true['Date'], y = df_true[i], name = i)
  for i in df_test.columns[1:]:
    fig.add_scatter(x= df_test['Date'], y = df_test[i], name = i)
  for i in df_fut.columns[1:]:
    fig.add_scatter(x= df_fut['Date'], y = df_fut[i], name = i)
  for i in df_xtra.columns[1:]:
    fig.add_scatter(x = df_xtra['Date'], y = df_xtra[i], name = i)
  fig.show()

def interactive_plot_single(df_true):
  fig = px.line(title = f'Price {symbol} Prediction')
  for i in df_true.columns[1:]:
    fig.add_scatter(x = df_true['Date'], y = df_true[i], name = i)
  fig.show()

def line_plot(df):
  plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
  plt.title(f'Price {symbol} Prediction')
  plt.plot(df.Close)
  plt.xlabel(df.index.name)
  plt.ylabel('Price')
  plt.grid()
  plt.show()

def trading_window(data):
  n = window
  data['Target Model'] = data[['Close']].shift(-n)
  return data

def check_day(date):
  if date.weekday() >= 5:
    print(date)

def gen_dt_df(bperiods):
  datetime_df = pd.date_range(historic_price_df.index.max()+timedelta(days=1), periods=bperiods, normalize=True)
  for x in datetime_df:
    if x.weekday() in (5,6):
      datetime_df = datetime_df.drop(pd.Timestamp(x))
  return datetime_df

def f_df():
  count = 1
  fut_df = gen_dt_df(window)
  while fut_df.shape[0] < window:
    fut_df = gen_dt_df(window+count)
    count += 1
  return fut_df

def create_datasets(x,y):
  split = math.ceil((percentage_test_dataset) * len(working_price_df))
  x_train = x[:len(X)-split]
  y_train = y[:len(X)-split]
  x_test = x[len(X)-split+1:]
  y_test = y[len(X)-split+1:]
  return [x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test]

historic_price_df = web.DataReader(symbol,data_source=stock_data_source,start=start_date,end=end_date).filter(['Close'])
working_price_df = historic_price_df.copy()

prediction_days = f_df()

prediction_df = pd.DataFrame(index=prediction_days)
prediction_df.index.name = 'Date'
prediction_df.reset_index(inplace=True)

shifted_df = trading_window(working_price_df)
second_validation_df = shifted_df[len(shifted_df)-window:].filter(['Close']).round(2)
shifted_df.dropna(inplace=True)

scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))

unscaled_X = shifted_df.iloc[:,0].values.round(2)
unscaled_Y = shifted_df.iloc[:,1].values.round(2)

unscaled_X = unscaled_X.reshape(unscaled_X.shape[0],1)
unscaled_Y = unscaled_Y.reshape(unscaled_Y.shape[0],1)

second_validation_unscaled = second_validation_df.iloc[:,0].values.round(2)
second_validation_unscaled = second_validation_unscaled.reshape(second_validation_unscaled.shape[0],1)

scaler.fit(unscaled_X,unscaled_Y)

X = scaler.transform(unscaled_X)
Y = scaler.transform(unscaled_Y)
Z = scaler.transform(second_validation_unscaled)

future = []

for i in range(historic_price_df.shape[0]-window,len(historic_price_df)):
  future.append([historic_price_df['Close'][i].round(2)])

future = scaler.transform(future)

X_train,X_test,Y_train,Y_test = train_test_split(X,Y,test_size=percentage_test_dataset)
#X_train,X_test,Y_train,Y_test = create_datasets(X,Y)

X_train = np.reshape(X_train,(X_train.shape[0],X_train.shape[1],1))
#X_test = np.reshape(X_test,(X_test.shape[0],X_test.shape[1],1))
#X_test = np.asarray(X_test)

early_stop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',mode='min',verbose=1,patience=15)

inputs = keras.layers.Input(shape = (X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2]))
tf = keras.layers.LSTM(500, return_sequences=True)(inputs)
tf = keras.layers.LSTM(300, return_sequences=True)(tf)
tf = keras.layers.LSTM(200, return_sequences=True)(tf)
tf = keras.layers.LSTM(100, return_sequences=True)(tf)
tf = keras.layers.LSTM(50, return_sequences=True)(tf)
outputs = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='linear')(tf)
model = keras.Model(inputs = inputs,outputs = outputs)
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='mse')
model.summary()

model.fit(X_train,Y_train, batch_size=128,epochs=100,validation_data=(X_test,Y_test),callbacks=[early_stop]);

losses = pd.DataFrame(model.history.history)
losses.plot()

validation_xtra = model.predict(Z)

validation_train = model.predict(X_test)

predictions = model.predict(future)

validation_train = validation_train.reshape(validation_train.shape[0],1)
validation_xtra = validation_xtra.reshape(validation_xtra.shape[0],1)
predictions = predictions.reshape(predictions.shape[0],1)

mae = mean_absolute_error(X_test,validation_train)
#mae

mse = mean_squared_error(Z,validation_xtra)
#mse

validation_train = scaler.inverse_transform(validation_train)
validation_xtra = scaler.inverse_transform(validation_xtra)
predictions = scaler.inverse_transform(predictions)

second_validation_df['Extra Validation'] = validation_xtra
second_validation_df.reset_index(inplace=True)

prediction_df['Prediction'] = predictions
#prediction_df.reset_index(inplace=True)

val_data_df = pd.DataFrame(historic_price_df[len(historic_price_df)-validation_train.shape[0]:])
val_data_df.reset_index(inplace=True)

val_data_df['Train Validation'] = validation_train

historic_price_df.reset_index(inplace=True)

interactive_plot(historic_price_df,val_data_df,second_validation_df,prediction_df)
```

Comment: Yes sure, what a good mood mate! cheers. @furas

Answer (score 0):

When you are splitting your data your own, you are not adding a **shuffle**. So you are training the model with the first 1000 samples (invented number), and testing with the last 200 samples.

Whereas, when you are using `train_test_split`, a shuffling is done automatically. That's the main difference.

It seems that your final samples are a little bit different, and the model can not learn how they will behave only with first sample. Which is quiet normal.

Comment: Thanks @alex-serra-marrugat, I thougth in that before and ran it with "shuffle=False" getting the same result. I just re-run it to re-check and works. In my previous run I guess I made something wrong. Very thanks by the way!

Comment: Glad my answer helps you!